# DataGrid Cell styling with Dynamic generating column

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I am getting dynamic columns in data table (because column generates dynamically so there is no model) which is binded to WPF data grid.These are autogenerated columns.I need to change the cell color of datagrid based on a condition.There is column (Progress) which has a comma seperated value for each column.These number will decide the color of column1,column2,column3's cells.I need a way to set the style color of individual cells by using the values from column (Progress) of particular columns.

```
| Coulmn1    | Coumn2        | Column3       | Progress         |
| 123        | ABC           | TRUE          | C1=0.5,C2=1,C3=0 |
| 456        | CDF           | TRUE          | C1=1,C2=1,C3=0   |
| 789        | EFG           | TRUE          | C1=0,C2=1,C3=0   |
```

The color will be `0=Red,0.5=LightRed,1=Green`, e.g.

```
| Coulmn1              | Coumn2          | Column3       | Progress         |
| 123   (LightRed)     | ABC (Green)     | TRUE    (Red) | C1=0.5,C2=1,C3=0 |
```

Comment: Create an Implicit Style for `DataGridCell` and set it's Background color using a Converter. The converter will need to know the data item of the row and the Column the cell is on, so it will probably need to be a `MultiValueConverter`. The converter will need to cast the data item into a `DataGridRow` object, obtain the `Progress` cell, and decide which color to return based on the Column. Alternatively, you could create a proper backing object for your DataGrid and parse your data into these objects, which would include a `Color` property that you could bind to. My preference is #2.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Helper:

```
  public class ColumnNameAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public TextAlignment TextAlignment { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public bool IsReadOnly { get; set; }
        public double MinWidth { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Helper to fill column attributes: header name, text alignment, editability and background color
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="name"></param>
        /// <param name="textAlignment"></param>
        /// <param name="isReadOnly"></param>
        /// <param name="color"></param>
        public ColumnNameAttribute(string name, TextAlignment textAlignment = TextAlignment.Left, bool isReadOnly = true, string color = "White")
        {
            Name = name;
            TextAlignment = textAlignment;
            Color = color;
            IsReadOnly = isReadOnly;
        }

        public ColumnNameAttribute(string name, double minWidth, TextAlignment textAlignment= TextAlignment.Left, bool isReadOnly = true, string color = "White")
        {
            Name = name;
            TextAlignment = textAlignment;
            IsReadOnly = isReadOnly;
            Color = color;
        }
    }
```

xaml.cs:

```
datagrid.AutoGeneratingColumn +=  dataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn;

 private void dataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
        {
            var desc = e.PropertyDescriptor as PropertyDescriptor;
            var att = desc.Attributes[typeof(ColumnNameAttribute)] as ColumnNameAttribute;
            if (att != null)
            {
                e.Column.IsReadOnly = att.IsReadOnly;
                e.Column.CellStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell));
 switch (att.Color)
                {
                    case "LightGreen":
                        //BorderBrushProperty looks better
                        e.Column.CellStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter( BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.PaleGreen)));
                        e.Column.CellStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBox.ToolTipProperty, "<Enter value>"));
                        break;
                }
                e.Column.Header = att.Name;
                e.Column.CellStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.TextAlignmentProperty, att.TextAlignment));
                if (att.MinWidth > 0) e.Column.MinWidth = att.MinWidth;
            }
        }
```

Object class:

```
public Example{
 [ColumnName("My Custom Name", TextAlignment.Right, false, "LightGreen")]
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```